# Click event to a custom button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a matrix of custom buttons (class FifteenButton I made that inherits Button). I want to have a click event for each button in the matrix that calls a method that does some work. But I don't want to write such method for each button in the matrix. So, I did something like this in `initializeComponent`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        fbarr[i, j].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.FifteenButton_Click);
```

and in `FifteenButton_Click` I want to know which button was clicked (preferrably i, j coordinates).

How should I go about doing something like that? Maybe in the EventArgs of `FifteenButton_Click`? But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The first argument is a `Control` reference to the sender.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks, if you want you can answer and I will pick you as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event hadler of the Click event receives two parameters

```
void FifteenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The sender parameter is the reference to the button clicked, so

```
void FifteenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button btn = sender as Button;
     if(btn != null)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Button clicked: " + btn.Text);
     }
}
```

However, if you want to retrieve the location of the button in the array used in your question, you need something more. For example you could use the Tag property to store the i j coordinates of the button.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        fbarr[i, j].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.FifteenButton_Click);
        fbarr[i, j].Tag = i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, in the event handler, you culd easily read the Tag property of the button and recover the indexes

```
void FifteenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button btn = sender as Button;
     if(btn != null)
     {
          string[] xy = btn.Tag.ToString().Split('_');
          Console.WriteLine("Button clicked: " + xy[0] + "," + xy[1]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do you check if `btn` is null? Only a FifteenButton can call this method so of course it will be a FifteenButton, why check?

Comment: Well, this is true, force of habit after the conversion with the as keyword. To be honest if I check the null I should check also the Tag property.